# Click after hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, flexbox

I'm trying to create a webpage for my future portfolio
Here is my link for [latecode-hub](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) and here is my code:

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Antic-Slab';
  src: url('AnticSlab-Regular.ttf');
}
.navigation{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navigation #chbox{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
.wrapper .hamburger{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;

}
.wrapper  .hamburger >div{
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.wrapper .hamburger .div1{ 
  
  top: 0px;
}

.wrapper .hamburger .div2{
 
  top: 10px;
}
.wrapper  .hamburger .div3{
 
  top: 20px;
}
.navigation #chbox:checked + .wrapper .hamburger >.div1{
  transform: rotate(-28deg);
  width: 90%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;

}
.navigation #chbox:checked + .wrapper .hamburger >.div2{
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-25px) ;
  width: 90%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;

}
.navigation #chbox:checked + .wrapper  .hamburger >.div3{
  transform: rotate(28deg);
  width: 90%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}


.wrapper #menu{
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  justify-items: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  transition: 0.5 ease;
  height: 0;
 
  
  
}
.wrapper #menu a{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Antic-Slab;
  
}
.navigation #chbox:checked .wrapper #menu:hover{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

}
@import 'firefly.css';

@font-face{
    font-family: 'Antic-Slab';
    src: url('AnticSlab-Regular.ttf');
}
body{
    background-color: rgba(124, 110, 204, 0.376);
    margin: 0;
    
    
}

.box1{
    order: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 60% 15% 15%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(26,28,32) 0%, rgb(49,54,66) 100%);
    background-size: 210vh 200vh;

}
.main-word{   
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    color :rgb(230,219,200);
    font-family: Antic-Slab;
   
    cursor:default;
      
}
.main-word >#main1{
    text-align: left;
    animation-name: main;
    animation-duration: 2s; 
}

.main-word >#main2{
    animation-name: main;
    animation-duration: 4s;    
}
#main2>span{
    color:rgb(144, 132, 189) ;   
}
.main-word >#main3{
    animation-name: main;
    animation-duration: 6s;       
}
    @keyframes main{
        0% {
        
            opacity: 0;
            
        
    }
        20%{
            opacity: 0.2;
            filter: blur(8px);

        }

        40%{
            opacity: 0.4;
            filter: blur(6px);
        }
        60% {
        
            opacity: 0.6;
            filter: blur(4px);
            
        
    }
        80%{
            opacity: 0.8;
            filter: blur(2px);

        }

        100%{
            opacity: 1;
            
        }
  
  

    }   

.down_writing{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
    color: white;
}
.arrow_down{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid white;
     border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
.arrow1{
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 20px;   
}
.box2{
   
    z-index: 1;
    
}

.box3{
    height: 200vh;
    background-color: inherit;
    
}
.box4{
    background-size: 210vh 200vh;

}
header{
    background-color: rgba(70, 127, 165, 0.123);  
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="personal portfolio webpage">
    <link href="personal webpage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="hamburger menu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Latecoder</title>   
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navigation">
                
                    
            <input type="checkbox" id="chbox" />
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="hamburger">  
                    <div class="div1"></div>
                    <div class="div2"></div>
                    <div class="div3"></div>  
                </div>
                
                <ul id="menu">
                    <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Projects</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
                        
                </ul>
    
            </div>
    </nav>       
            

        <div class="box1">
            
            <div class="main-word">
                <div id="main1">Hello</div>
                <div id="main2">I'm <span>Cagatay</span> </div>
                <div id="main3">This is my webpage</div>
            </div>
            <div class=down_writing>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
                <div class="firefly"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow1"><i class="arrow_down"></i></div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="box2">
            
                
            
        </div>
        <div class="box3">
            <div>
               Yeah that one is me 
            </div>
            <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
            <div> Yeah thats me</div>
            <div><img src="" alt=""></div>

        </div>
        <div class="box4"></div>
    
    
       
    <footer>

    </footer>
    
</body>

</html>
```

I want to add a hover coming from the right side when I click on the hamburger menu, background box going come from right to left and menu will appear with it, something like a mixing of [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sidenav_buttons.asp)  I can add javascript if it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kmdyuwt8/2/

You need to add an open class

```css
.wrapper #menu.show {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

And toggle it on hover.

```js
let elm = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
function toggleMenu() {
  document.querySelector('#menu').classList.toggle('show');
}
elm.onmouseenter = toggleMenu;
elm.onmouseleave = toggleMenu;
```

Your current css has some behavioral bugs in it, so cleaning it up will fix the minor inconveniences.

Comment: did you add anything else or did anything on code, I couldn't make it work, it is working here but not in my laptop or my code, do I have to add anything apart from <script> tag?  I am so close to breaking my laptop...

Comment: dont think so, you can always compare the type next to each other

Comment: dont forget that my answer have css and js in it

Comment: well, I was thinking to rewrite the code from the beginning, after I will add your code and see what's gonna happen, thank you for help[